# Error with summary function in R with a corpus

Tags: r

Error with corpus function in R

Hello!
I transformed data_char_ukimmig2010 into a corpus like this:

```
data<-data_char_ukimmig2010
data <- corpus(data, 
                     docvars = data.frame(party = names(data)))
```

Then, I tried using the summary function but i have an error :

```
summary(data)
Error in if (...length() && any(...names() == "Dimnames")) .Object@Dimnames <- fixupDN(.Object@Dimnames) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I do not understand why

Comment: Can you provide `dput(data_char_ukimmig2010)` to make your post reproducible?

Comment: data_char_ukimmig2010 is a character vector from quanteda.

Comment: I ran your code (`library(quanteda); data <- data_char_ukimmig2010; data <- corpus(data, docvars = data.frame(party = names(data))); summary(data)`) and I could not reproduce your error. The `summary()` function worked as expected. Are you running up-to-date versions of R, RStudio, and relevant packages?

Comment: I have the same issue, e.g. when trying to do `quanteda::data_corpus_inaugural %>% summary()`. Still don't know how to fix it. Just downloaded the most recent R/R Studio version.